# Uninstalling applications in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In our app, we are uninstalling some third-party applications and are using the [app_uninstaller](https://pub.dev/packages/app_uninstaller) flutter(2.5.3) plugin to do so. According to [crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics?gclsrc=ds&gclsrc=ds) this plugin has the most number of crash events, affecting 206 users out of 486 crash events (Yesterday's data). Is there any other way we could uninstall apps? Code for app uninstall:

```
var isUninstalled = await AppUninstaller.Uninstall("com.package_name");
```

And this is the exception we are getting:

```
Fatal Exception: kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: Not yet implemented
   at com.frendyapp.app_uninstaller.AppUninstallerPlugin.onDetachedFromActivity(AppUninstallerPlugin.kt:80)
   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.detachFromActivity(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:389)
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onDetach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:632)
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.release(FlutterActivity.java:622)
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onDestroy(FlutterActivity.java:643)
   at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7460)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1250)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4655)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4686)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5()
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1807)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6971)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 2):

What I did was remove the uninstaller plugin completely and call the native android side using the `MethodChannel`.

On the native side, I am uninstalling the applications using Intent. Please check the below code for reference:

**Flutter Side:**

```
const platform = MethodChannel('com.flutter.uninstall');
String package = 'com.package.name';

var uninstallResult = await platform.invokeMethod("Uninstall", {
  "package": package,
});
```

**Native Android Side:**

```
private val CHANNEL_UNINSTALL = "com.flutter.uninstall"


MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor, CHANNEL_UNINSTALL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
  if (call.method == "Uninstall") {
    val packageName = call.argument<String>("package")
    Log.e("Package Name", "$packageName")

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE)
    intent.data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true)
    result.success("uninstall_started")
  }
}
```